# Как получать различные события / статистику из матчей CS:GO в реальном времени?

Tags: разработка-игр

Необходимо получать различные события из матча CS:GO в реальном времени. Я погуглил и нашел несколько возможных вариантов решения этой задачи. Первый - использовать API сервера и получать базовую информацию (вроде ника игроков и текущего счета), однако этого мало.
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Второй - подключаться к серверу через `rcon`, однако проблема в том, что задача подразумевает получение статистики любого матча, а не с принадлежащих нам игровых серверов.

Третий - использовать SourceTV. Тут тоже есть свои нюансы (например, он может быть не включен на сервере. Кроме того, по дефолту в конфигах сервера стоит задержка 90 секунд или что-то вроде того), но это не столь важно. Я не нашел никаких описаний протокола его работы или чего-то вроде того, официальный портал valve на эту тему молчит.

Буду благодарен, если предложите иные пути решения или посоветуете что-то по поводу SourceTV.

Comment: > Однако этого мало - вы не в силах расширить API, так что придется довольствоваться тем, что есть.